# pymc3 SQLite backend, specify list of variables to track

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I am fitting a hierarchical model where one variable has a shape>10K and the model requires 500+k samples to converge. I would like to use a persistent backend for trace, so that I can compare different models later.
I tried to use SQLite backend, I got the following error:

> /opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc3/backends/sqlite.pyc in
>   _create_table(self)
>       123                 statement = template.format(table=varname,
>       124                                             value_cols=colnames)
>   --> 125                 self.db.cursor.execute(statement)
>       126 
>       127     def _create_insert_queries(self, chain):
>
> OperationalError: too many columns on individual_freq

I assume this is because I am trying to save a trace for all my vars, including a vector variable with shape>10K. I don't need/want to save trace for a vector - I am only interested in top-level variables.
When using memory backend, I am able to specify the list of variables explicitly like this:

```
trace = pm.sample(1000000, step, start=start, progressbar=False,   
                  trace=[alpha,beta,uplift,mo_drop])
```

But when using SQLite, I can only specify:

```
backend = SQLite('beta_poisson_monthly_drop.sqlite')
trace = pm.sample(1000000, step, progressbar=False,
                  trace=backend)
```

What I want to do, is something like this:

```
backend = SQLite('beta_poisson_monthly_drop.sqlite')
trace = pm.sample(1000000, step, progressbar=False,
                  trace=backend, vars=[alpha,beta,uplift,mo_drop])
```

Is it possible? Should this be a feature request?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try the `vars` argument to `SQLite`.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. There is, indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a vars argument in SQLite init method:

```
backend = SQLite('beta_poisson_monthly_drop.sqlite',
                 vars=[alpha,beta,uplift,mo_drop])
trace = pm.sample(1000000, step, progressbar=False, trace=backend)
```